# Norm of the adjoint representation and invariant Riemannian distance

Tags: functional-analysis, representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $G:=\text{SL}(d,\mathbb R)$ and let $Z$ denote the center of $G$ which is a finite cyclic subgroup. Consider a right $G$-invariant Riemannian distance $d$ on the homogeneous space $G/Z$. Let $\text{Ad}:G \to GL(\mathfrak{g})$ denote the adjoint representation of $G$. I want to show that there are positive constants $c_1, c_2$ such that for all $g \in G$ (with an abuse of notation identified with the equivalence class $gZ$), we have the inequality ($\|\text{Ad}(g) \|$ is viewed as the operator norm for the linear operator $\text{Ad}(g)$ on the Lie algebra, treated as an inner product space):

$$c_1 d(g, I_d) \le \log(\|\text{Ad}(g) \|) \le c_2 d(g, I_d) $$

The reason that I took $G/Z$ is that is $g$ is in the center then $\text{Ad}(g)$ becomes trivial. I want to avoid such trivial cases.

I found that even the case when $g$ is diagonal is hard for me:

Suppose $g=diag(a_1,\dots, a_d) \in G$. $\text{Ad}(g)(X)= gXg^{-1}$. I don't know how to find the operator norm of $\text{Ad}(g)$. Also, I don't know how to estimate/determine $d(g, I_d)$.

Comment: This looks correct. What is the motivation behind the question?

Comment: @MoisheKohan This is something I learnt in a conference. They said both sides are related to the eigenvalues of $g$ somehow, but not able to give me a proof.